# Copy text from browser window using pywinauto/pyautogui

Tags: windows-7-x64, pywinauto, pyautogui

I tried searching this but no use.
I am trying to select/copy the content from a chrome/mozilla using pywinauto/pyautogui.
All I am able to achieve till now is to identify the screen position of the text, start selecting from left to right after left-click.
Is there an elegant way to do this, because the screen sizes are different and this solution will not fit for all users.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

pywinauto 0.6.0 can use MS UI Automation to find the control containing the text. But Chrome should be started with `chrome --force-renderer-accessibility` cmd flag as [described here](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/wiki/How-to-enable-accessibility-(tips-and-tricks)).

Browsers also can spawn separate process for every tab. So `app = Application(backend="uia").start("chrome --force-renderer-accessibility")` may be insufficient. You may have to reconnect to another process by `app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path='chrome.exe', title='Tab title')` to work with the tab. Another option is to use `chrome_tab = Desktop(backend="uia")["Tab title"]` to make everything process-agnostic.

More detailed code for the text retrieval depends on your case. Hope it helps.

P.S. Currently we have no example for a browser but have plans to write it at some moment. If you succeed with that, please share your results if possible.